# Not able to extract data using scrapy with class names containing spaces and hyphens

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I have to extract text from a tag with multiple class names, where the class names contain spaces and hyphens.

Example:

```
<div class="info">
    <span class="price sale">text1</span>
    <span class="title ng-binding">some text</span>
</div>
```

When i use the code:

```
response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'price sale')]/text()").extract()
```

I am able to get text1 but when I use:

```
response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'title ng-binding')]/text()").extract()
```

I get an empty list. Why is this happening and how to handle this?

Comment: That's weird, it works for me (tested on both Scrapy 1.3.3 and 1.4.0).

Comment: hi i have the same problem in 2022 , have you solved the problem and how ?thanks

Answer (score 9):

The expression you're looking for is:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'title') and contains(@class, 'ng-binding')]
```

I highly suggest XPath visualizer, which can help you debug xpath expressions easily. It can be found here:

http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/

Or with CSS try

```
response.css("span.title.ng-binding")
```

Or there is a chance that element with `ng-binding` is loaded via Javascript/Ajax hence not included in initial server response.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the spaces with "." in your code when using response.css().
In your case you can try:

```
response.css("span.title.ng-binding::text").extract()
```

This code should return the text you are looking for.